# Error on Resize of Bootstrap Dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

whenever a user resizes a window, window resize function is triggered, and I am not sure why  `$('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown('true');` is used

code :

```
$(window).resize(function () {
                if ($(window).width() <= PG.globalVars.SM_max_width) {
                    $('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown('true');
                    //$('.dropdown-toggle').bs.dropdown('true');
                    //$('.dropdown-toggle').attr('aria-expanded','true');
                    $(".menu-links, .sub-menu-first-child").off("click");
                    if (!$('.score-navbar-header').hasClass("attached")) {
                        $('.score-navbar-header button').on('click', function () {
                            $(".navbar-collapse.in").collapse('hide');
                            $(".score-megamenu-dropdown").removeClass("attachDT").off("mouseover mouseout");
                            PG.spMenuStart();
                        });
                    }
                    else {
                        $(".page-wrapper, .score-navbar-header, .score-footer").removeClass("hamburger");
                        $(".score-nav-wrapper").parents(".container").removeClass("width-override");
                        $(".score-nav-wrapper").parents(".score-center").removeClass("paddingzero");
                        $(".score-nav-wrapper").parents(".score-column1 ").removeClass("marginzero");

                        $('.search-icon-mob-wrap').parent('.container').removeClass("hamburger");
                        $('.pg-search-box-wrap').parent('.container').removeClass("hamburger");

                        $(".navbar-nav").removeClass("nav-baractive");
                        if ($(".mask-menu").length != 0) {
                            $(".mask-menu").remove();
                            $(".navbar-collapse.in").collapse('hide');
                        }
                    }

                }
                else {
                    $(".page-wrapper, .score-navbar-header, .score-footer").removeClass("hamburger");
                    $(".score-nav-wrapper").parents(".container").removeClass("width-override");
                    $(".score-nav-wrapper").parents(".score-center").removeClass("paddingzero");
                    $(".score-nav-wrapper").parents(".score-column1 ").removeClass("marginzero");

                    $('.search-icon-mob-wrap').parent('.container').removeClass("hamburger");
                    $('.pg-search-box-wrap').parent('.container').removeClass("hamburger");

                    $(".navbar-nav").removeClass("nav-baractive");
                    if ($(".mask-menu").length != 0) {
                        $(".mask-menu").remove();
                        $(".navbar-collapse.in").collapse('hide');
                    }
                    PG.toggleNavbarMethod();

                    $(".score-menu-list").removeClass("hide");
                }
            });
```

Error : 
**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined**

can anyone please shade any light on this issue?

[image]
I would Appreciate any help.

[image]

console.log output  :

[image]

Comment: It would really help if the code was not minimized

Comment: @xpy : this is a bootstrap library

Comment: @xpy , i have added un minified JS Error Pls. check

Comment: Apparently data[option] is expected to be a function and is not, what do you get if you `console.log` `data` and `option` at that point?

Comment: @xpy, have attached the output as img..... if (typeof option == 'string') 
        console.log(data);
        console.log(this);
        console.log(option);

        data[option].call($this)

    })

Comment: I don't think `true` should be there: `$('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown('true');` and I really can't tell why it is there... sorry

Comment: @xpy, thanks for ur time :)